Quarkus WebSocket: cannot connect to a web socket
I followed a guide for implementing WebSocket extension in Quarkus. https://quarkus.io/guides/websockets
I adopted my code and did not manage to connect to a web socket.
Then I generated a new application on https://code.quarkus.io/ with only one extension (quarkus-websockets).

This is a class which define a WebSocket url.
package org.acme;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.websocket.EncodeException;
import jakarta.websocket.OnClose;
import jakarta.websocket.OnError;
import jakarta.websocket.OnMessage;
import jakarta.websocket.OnOpen;
import jakarta.websocket.Session;
import jakarta.websocket.server.PathParam;
import jakarta.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;

import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

@ServerEndpoint("/start-websocket/{name}")
@ApplicationScoped
public class StartWebSocket {

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println("onOpen> " + name);
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session, @PathParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println("onClose> " + name);
}

@OnError
public void onError(Session session, @PathParam("name") String name, Throwable throwable) {
    System.out.println("onError> " + name + ": " + throwable);
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, @PathParam("name") String name) {
    System.out.println("onMessage> " + name + ": " + message);
  }
}

I build a project and start it, the server is hosted on http://localhost:8080.
I specified this url ws://localhost:8080/start-websocket/test and tried to connect via Postman, but the error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8080 is thrown.
Any ideas what could be wrong? Do I require some additional properties which are not described in the guide?

I could not find any fix.
My solution was to simply change to the WebSockets Next.
https://quarkus.io/guides/websockets-next-tutorial
